# implement scrollView events in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

[RE-EDIT]

I am trying to implement these events in the scrollView:

- OnSingleTap
- OnDoubleTap
- PaningStart
- OnPanning
- PanningEnd
- PinchingStart
- OnPinching
- PinchingEnd
- RotatingStart
- OnRotating
- RotatingEnd
- OnLongPress

The application is a collection of UI parts that function as one UI part. I have categorized them under a relative layout which I've placed in the scrollView.

I am completely new at this and I would appreciate any help offered. Thanks.

[RE-EDIT]

code sample:

```
public class Mobclassname extends ScrollView {
    private Object[] children;
    private ArrayList<Object> uiParts = null;
    private Context context;


    public MobGadgetFile(Context context, NSDictionary dict) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setProperties(dict);

        uiParts = ObjectMgr.createUIParts(context, children);
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

        MobUtils.addUIparts(uiParts, rl);


        HorizontalScrollView hscroll = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
        hscroll.addView(rl);
        this.addView(hscroll);

    }
```

I am doing everything in code therefore I don't have any xml layout file. This is my specification.

Thanks.

Comment: A little more info would be nice - like what exactly do you mean by "trying to implement"? What functionality is it you want for the different events?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts? Please advise

Comment: Post the layout xml - it's easier to give advice if you provide some actual information in.